# How do you execute code after the app initialization is complete?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

In a Silverlight Windows Phone 7 app, how can you organise the startup sequence so you can execute code AFTER the app has initalized and loaded (i.e., after the splash screen goes away and the app is visible)?

I have a main page constructor that looks like this:

```
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            loadSettings();
            getLocation();
        }
```

The `getLocation()` function gets the phone's location with the `GeoCoordinateWatcher` object. The initialisation of this can take up to a minute, and in this time the splash screen of the app is visible.

How can I organise the code so that the app is first initialized, THEN I can show a waiting screen of my own with more text saying "Getting Location" etc.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a handler for the Loaded event and then call loadSettings and getLocation. You might want to do this in a BackgroundWorker to keep things responsive.

Comment: That would make sense, thanks.. Having trouble binding the event to a function though. I am doing something silly: MainPage.LoadedEvent += startMap; does not work...